# install deluged and deluged-console in a debian VM and serve new torrent

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

I would like to share a local file via torrent. I created a torrent at home on my laptop with `Transmission` on Ubuntu 19.10 and successfully added the tracker `udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80/announce`.

Now I want to download the file, I share at home on my laptop, on my Debian 10 VM on my XEN server via `deluged-console`.
I used this Howto: https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient

I only need one user that runs `deluged` and the `deluge-console`, so I just did this:

```
apt install deluged deluge-console psmisc
useradd deluge-user
su deluge-user
deluged
deluge-console "config -s allow_remote True"
deluge-console "config allow_remote"
deluge-console
```

Then I copied the magnet link from the file in Transmission *(NOTE: you have to first add the tracker, then copy the magnet link)* on my Ubuntu laptop, and added it in the deludge-console by the command:

```
add magnet:?xt=urn:btih:....
```

And it started the torrent, but there is nothing transferred:

```
Name: Testfile.mp3                                                                                                                                                                   
ID: 6d288a34b359cdb5406f6858ab51edbacecefbd6                                                                                                                                                                                        
State: Downloading Down Speed: 0.0 KiB/s Up Speed: 0.0 KiB/s                                                                                                                                                                        
Seeds: 0 (1) Peers: 0 (1) Availability: 0.00                                                                                                                                                                                        
Size: 0.0 KiB/0.0 KiB Ratio: -1.000                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Seed time: 0 days 00:00:00 Active: 0 days 19:22:34                                                                                                                                                                                  
Tracker status: openbittorrent.com: Announce OK                                                                                                                                                                                     
Progress: 0.00% [~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~]  
C: 0 (200) D: 0.0 KiB U: 0.0 KiB DHT: 293                                                                                                                                              
info
```

Am I missing something?

The deluged in my Debian VM seems to work fine: If I add another torrent from somewhere it downloads it just fine. Maybe I have to forward some ports for my laptop? That would not be possible on my WiFi hotspot in which I have no ability to forward ports.

Or do I have to upload the file to my server first per SSH and seed it from my online server? How would I create the magnet link there?

Please provide a solution, how I can **share a file via torrent**.

Comment: forgive me for being obtuse, you explicitly mention creating the tracker but are you actively seeding from the original machine?

Comment: How do I have to actively seed? I left running transmission in the original machine for three days. But maybe it cannot send it's seed correctly? Do I have to open a certain port or something, I'm missing?